# Radio button will select when linear layout clicked in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have created a 1 radio group that contains 2 linear layouts. These 2 linear layouts contain 1 radio button each. The linear layout was created only for applying the style for both radio group and text view. when we checked the radio button that button has checked. Its working fine but I want to trigger the radio button when I click the linear layout also. Is there any solution to fix this issue.
`

```
                       <RadioGroup

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                          >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                style="@style/RadioButton">
                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/entireplace"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:button="@null"                                       
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"                                        
                                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                                    android:text="@string/entireplace"
                                    />
                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                       
                                    android:text="@string/entire_txt"/>
                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="0.3dp"/>
                            </LinearLayout>


                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                style="@style/RadioButton">
                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/privatepalce
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:button="@null"
                                    android:drawablePadding="30dp"                                       
                                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                                    android:text="@string/privateroom"
                                    />
                                <TextView

                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/pvt_txt"/>
                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="0.3dp""/>
                            </LinearLayout>   

                        </RadioGroup>
```

`

```
  val onRadioButtonCheckedListener =
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if (!isChecked) return@OnCheckedChangeListener
                if (previousCheckedCompoundButton != null) {
                    previousCheckedCompoundButton!!.isChecked = false
                    previousCheckedCompoundButton = buttonView
                } else {
                    previousCheckedCompoundButton = buttonView
                }
            }


        binding.entireplace.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener)
        binding.private.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener)
```

Comment: You could set the onClick listener to the LinearLayout and then in the on Click method set the radio button

Answer (score 0):

Do not place linearlayout inside radiogroup, otherwise radio buttons will act as separate radio button(that means every radio button can be seleted or deselected at one time).
Second thing you asked that you want the radio button to be checked/unchecked when you click on the linearlayout, can be done by calling setChecked(boolean) method of radio button upon linearlayout click.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not put Any layout as a child inside RadioGroup**

**RadioGroup can only handle RadioButton as child**